# img path in wordpress text editor

Tags: php, html, wordpress, image, path

I'm currently trying to plug a html theme to wordpress. For that I'm copy pasting HTML in the text editor, but it gave me a weird problem with my img path...

for example:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/_include/img/slider-images/1.jpg" alt="Image" data-fullwidthcentering="on">
```

It looks like the src is not closing when I'm checking the source code on Chrome and I can't find why. The closing quotation mark appear as &#8221 ; instead of ”
could it be an encoding problem? I'm out of solutions...

ps: I'm using

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

in my function.php

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use PHP in the content editor, just write the full path to your image.

```
<img src="/css/_include/img/slider-images/1.jpg" alt="Image" data-fullwidthcentering="on">
```